# ORACLE one hot encoding: Use PIVOT operator for all available columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, one-hot-encoding

Assume I have following table named t1:

```
CLID PRODUCT
1    A
1    B
2    A
2    C
3    A
3    C
```

What i need to reach is a some kind of one-hot-encoding on 'PRODUCT' field.
In Oracle we can do this at least in this way:

```
select * from(
    select clid, product 
    from t1
    pivot(
        count(product)
        for product 
        in('A', 'B', 'C')
    )
)
```

And after that we get result:

```
CLID A B C
1    1 1 0
2    1 0 1 
3    1 0 1
```

But the problem happens when we have large amount of products (assume 1000 items), and in this case it would be super inconvenient to put all that products into IN condition.

So my question is if there any way to avoid putting all possible values into 'IN'?
If there is no such option then maybe there is some another way to do one-hot-encoding in Oracle sql(or pl/sql?)?

Comment: Oracle may not support enough columns to support your query.

Comment: Is your end result supposed to be the table with all those columns, or a single value ('110', '101', '101') for each CLID, or something else? And is there a separate list of the products somewhere, maybe in another table?

Comment: In the end result I need values in CLID column being unique(not 1,1,2,3 but 1,2,3 only)also  i need to create additional columns named as product values (original PRODUCT field need to be deleted). In my example you can see that we obtained 3 new columns(A, B and C), and values in those columns are 1 or 0 only (1 stands for presence of product(name of column says us which product exactly) for certain CLID value, 0 stands for absence). 
No, in my case i don't have another table with product list, but i can create it

Comment: What will consume this data? It doesn't seem very useful to a human; but if it will be processed elsewhere later then you could maybe produce it as XML - you can do an XML pivot with a query in the `in()` clause. Otherwise it's maybe something a reporting layer should do.

Comment: Well, actually you are 100% right, for human it is not very useful :) But i need this procedure to be done in order to put retrieved data into machine learning model, since they work only with unique case data. So in order to capture client products we need to create columns for each product with values 1 or 0.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that I am using options from DBMS_DATA_MINING package which is part of Oracle DB EE

Comment: Which oracle version are you using ?

Comment: Currently I'm using 12c Enterprise Edition Release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PL/SQL anonymous block to build the query automatically no matter how many distinct products you have in your table, but you need to understand that you can't put more than 1000 values into a pivot clause, as you can't have more than 1000 columns.

I would do something like this ( assuming always less 1000 values )

**Test case ( create the table and the test values )**

```
SQL> create table t ( CLID number , PRODUCT varchar2(10) )  ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t ( clid , product )
  2  with x ( a , b ) as
(
select 1  ,  'A' from dual union all
select 1  ,  'B' from dual union all
select 2  ,  'A' from dual union all
select 2  ,  'C' from dual union all
select 3  ,  'A' from dual union all
select 3  ,  'C' from dual union all
select 4  ,  'D' from dual union all
select 4  ,  'E' from dual union all
select 5  ,  'B' from dual union all
select 5  ,  'C' from dual union all
select 5  ,  'D' from dual union all
select 5  ,  'E' from dual
)
select a , b from x ;

12 rows created.

SQL> commit ;

Commit complete.
```

**PLSQL construction**

Then, to get automatically the query no matter how many different products

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited lines 220 pages 0
declare
v_query       clob;
out_string    varchar2(100);
cursor c_ids 
is 
select distinct product, count(distinct(product)) over () tot_rows from t order by 1 asc;
procedure print_clob_to_output (p_clob in clob)
    is
      l_offset     pls_integer := 1;
      l_chars      pls_integer;
    begin
        loop
            exit when l_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);
            l_chars := dbms_lob.instr(p_clob, chr(10), l_offset, 1);
            if l_chars is null or l_chars = 0 then
                l_chars := dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob) + 1;
            end if;
            dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, l_chars - l_offset, l_offset));
            l_offset := l_chars + 1;
        end loop;
    end print_clob_to_output;
begin
    dbms_output.enable(null);
    for item in c_ids 
    loop
        if item.tot_rows >= 1000
        then 
            raise_application_error(-20001,'Maximum number of 1000 columns are not allowed',true);
        end if;
        out_string := item.product;
        if c_ids%rowcount = 1 
        then 
            v_query := 'select * from (';
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,'  select *  ');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,' from t '); 
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,' pivot( '); 
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,' count(product) '); 
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,' for product in ( '''||out_string||''' , ');
        elsif c_ids%rowcount < item.tot_rows then
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,' '''||out_string||''' ,');
        else 
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
            dbms_lob.append(v_query,' '''||out_string||''' ) ');
        end if;
    end loop;
    dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
    dbms_lob.append(v_query,' ) )');
    print_clob_to_output(v_query);
end;
/
```

**Execution**

```
SQL> @query.sql
SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited lines 220 pages 0
SQL>     declare
  2      v_query       clob;
  3      out_string    varchar2(100);
  4      cursor c_ids
  5      is
  6      select distinct product, count(distinct(product)) over () tot_rows from t order by 1 asc;
  7      procedure print_clob_to_output (p_clob in clob)
  8          is
  9            l_offset     pls_integer := 1;
 10            l_chars      pls_integer;
 11          begin
 12              loop
 13                  exit when l_offset > dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);
 14                  l_chars := dbms_lob.instr(p_clob, chr(10), l_offset, 1);
 15                  if l_chars is null or l_chars = 0 then
 16                      l_chars := dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob) + 1;
 17                  end if;
 18                  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, l_chars - l_offset, l_offset));
 19                  l_offset := l_chars + 1;
 20              end loop;
 21          end print_clob_to_output;
 22      begin
 23          dbms_output.enable(null);
 24          for item in c_ids
 25          loop
 26              if item.tot_rows >= 1000
 27              then
 28                  raise_application_error(-20001,'Maximum number of 1000 columns are not allowed',true);
 29              end if;
 30              out_string := item.product;
 31              if c_ids%rowcount = 1
 32              then
 33                  v_query := 'select * from (';
 34                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
 35                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,'  select *  ');
 36                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
 37                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,' from t ');
 38                                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
 39                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,' pivot( ');
 40                                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
 41                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,' count(product) ');
 42                                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
 43                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,' for product in ( '''||out_string||''' , ');
 44                          elsif c_ids%rowcount < item.tot_rows then
 45                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
 46                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,' '''||out_string||''' ,');
 47              else
 48                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
 49                  dbms_lob.append(v_query,' '''||out_string||''' ) ');
 50              end if;
 51          end loop;
 52          dbms_lob.append(v_query,''||chr(10)||'');
 53          dbms_lob.append(v_query,' ) )');
 54          print_clob_to_output(v_query);
 55      end;
 56      /
select * from (
select *
from t
pivot(
count(product)
for product in ( 'A' ,
'B' ,
'C' ,
'D' ,
'E' )
) )

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from (
select *
from t
pivot(
count(product)
for product in ( 'A' ,
'B' ,
'C' ,
'D' ,
'E' )
) ) ;

      CLID        'A'        'B'        'C'        'D'        'E'
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1          0          0          0
         2          1          0          1          0          0
         4          0          0          0          1          1
         5          0          1          1          1          1
         3          1          0          1          0          0
```